# Event triggers don't work on field elements in spring roo

Tags: javascript, spring-roo

I'm trying to use the **onblur** event in a create.jspx page but it doesn't fire. Do i need to edit something else for it to work?

This is the create.jspx page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <form:create id="fc_org_rooinaction_taskmanager_model_Task" modelAttribute="task" path="/tasks" render="${empty dependencies}" z="93eOjqRPoEhu9mi9qUmUfCOZKd0=">
        <field:textarea field="description" id="c_org_rooinaction_taskmanager_model_Task_description" required="true" z="zNvxTl9doPKsiJUnOX7KJNQpMC8="/>
        <field:checkbox field="completed" id="c_org_rooinaction_taskmanager_model_Task_completed" z="5zv/49txPJAAAPeAgZM62nofTFs="/>        
    <input id="inputField"/>
    </form:create>    
    <form:dependency dependencies="${dependencies}" id="d_org_rooinaction_taskmanager_model_Task" render="${not empty dependencies}" z="LRiLPref3RLI6Z8pks9LvWX5VuM="/>
```

Then i write the javascript onblur event handler for id=_description_id, the code below doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById("_description_id").onblur=function(){   
     alert(document.getElementById("_description_id").value);
}
```

But if i change the id with that of a regular input element (id=inputField) it works:

```
document.getElementById("inputField").onblur=function(){    
     alert(document.getElementById("_description_id").value);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the id of the element you are trying to set `onblur` callback in the former case?

Comment: Yes. The id is correct. Even though it has a different value in the file, when i check it with firebug the id is the one that i wrote it. Another way to know its correct is that if write an alert on that element it shows its correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring roo elements are dojo elements when then rendered on the screen. You need to add event listner for dojo.

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId(""),"blur",function(){
});
```